# How to make cloud reco app using vuforia

Tags: cloud, vuforia

I am working on a cloud recognition application using vuforia.
I want to modify the sample cloud reco app of vuforia samples to tell the user the name of object which is being recognized. Can anyone help me with it ?

since its just a prototype with just 10 objects. should I use audio files or TTS as audio output source ?

any reference material ?

Answer (score 0):

Please do your own research before posting such questions. To get you started on Cloud Reco, refer the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tksyhVlIMQ

As for your application, you want to name the objects recognized, in AR. Vuforia now allows  us to upload objects into the target manager, whether it is an image or cylinder/box, or even a multiple dimension object.

Upload these into Vuforia Database (Database should be for cloud reco. If not, create a new database for it) and get the Client Keys.

Now you can import the Cloud reco prefab and add a text on top to augment.

Hope this helped. :)